# Remote ejb call from tomcat6 to jboss5 causing: Could not dereference object exception

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, jboss, ejb

I am using Jboss5.1, Tomcat 6, Ejb3.0

I was trying to do simple Ejb remote call from Tomcat6 servlet to remote Stateless bean which deployed on Jboss5.1.

I added all required jars to the tomcat lib dir. and still after lots of struggle I get this error while trying to lookup

Thats the exception:

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Could not dereference object [Root exception is java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException]
      at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getObjectInstanceWrapFailure(NamingContext.java:1504)
      at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:803)
      at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:686)
      at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
      at com.MomSetUp.setUp(MomSetUp.java:46)
      at org.apache.jsp.test.test_jsp._jspService(test_jsp.java:58)
      at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
      at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
      at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
      at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
      at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
      at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
      at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
      at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
      at $Proxy0.createProxyBusiness(Unknown Source)
      at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.objectfactory.session.SessionProxyObjectFactory.createProxy(SessionProxyObjectFactory.java:129)
      at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.objectfactory.session.stateless.StatelessSessionProxyObjectFactory.getProxy(StatelessSessionProxyObjectFactory.java:79)
      at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.objectfactory.ProxyObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(ProxyObjectFactory.java:158)
      at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:304)
      at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getObjectInstance(NamingContext.java:1479)
      at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getObjectInstanceWrapFailure(NamingContext.java:1496)
      ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
      at org.jboss.remoting.InvokerRegistry.loadClientInvoker(InvokerRegistry.java:453)
      at org.jboss.remoting.InvokerRegistry.createClientInvoker(InvokerRegistry.java:352)
      at org.jboss.remoting.Client.connect(Client.java:512)
      at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.InvokeRemoteInterceptor.invoke(InvokeRemoteInterceptor.java:59)
      at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
      at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.remoting.IsLocalProxyFactoryInterceptor.invoke(IsLocalProxyFactoryInterceptor.java:72)
      at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
      at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.PojiProxy.invoke(PojiProxy.java:62)
      ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.util.propertyeditor.PropertyEditors.mapJavaBeanProperties(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/Properties;Z)V
      at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.mapJavaBeanProperties(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:1280)
      at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.setup(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:496)
      at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.<init>(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:275)
      at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.SocketClientInvoker.<init>(SocketClientInvoker.java:78)
      at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.TransportClientFactory.createClientInvoker(TransportClientFactory.java:39)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
      at org.jboss.remoting.InvokerRegistry.loadClientInvoker(InvokerRegistry.java:453)
      at org.jboss.remoting.InvokerRegistry.createClientInvoker(InvokerRegistry.java:352)
      at org.jboss.remoting.Client.connect(Client.java:512)
      at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.InvokeRemoteInterceptor.invoke(InvokeRemoteInterceptor.java:59)
      at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
      at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.remoting.IsLocalProxyFactoryInterceptor.invoke(IsLocalProxyFactoryInterceptor.java:72)
      at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
      at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.PojiProxy.invoke(PojiProxy.java:62)
      at $Proxy0.createProxyBusiness(Unknown Source)
      at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.objectfactory.session.SessionProxyObjectFactory.createProxy(SessionProxyObjectFactory.java:129)
      at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.objectfactory.session.stateless.StatelessSessionProxyObjectFactory.getProxy(StatelessSessionProxyObjectFactory.java:79)
      at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.objectfactory.ProxyObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(ProxyObjectFactory.java:158)
      at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:304)
      at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getObjectInstance(NamingContext.java:1479)
      at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getObjectInstanceWrapFailure(NamingContext.java:1496)
      at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:803)
      at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:686)
      at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
      at com.MomSetUp.setUp(MomSetUp.java:46)
      at org.apache.jsp.test.test_jsp._jspService(test_jsp.java:58)
      at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
      at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
      at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
      at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
      at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
      at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
      at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
      at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
      at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.InvokeRemoteInterceptor.invoke(InvokeRemoteInterceptor.java:72)
```

this is my tomcat client:

```
 public void setUp() throws Exception {
                try {

                      Properties p = new Properties();
                      p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                                  "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
                      p.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");

                      p.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "192.168.200.32:1099"); // if not using


                      InitialContext context = new InitialContext(p);

                      // String lookupStr = "Mom/DispactherBeanRemote/remote";
                      String lookupStr = "DispactherBean/remote";
                      //System.out.println("lookup =" + context.lookup(lookupStr));

                      DispactherBeanRemote dispactherBean = (DispactherBeanRemote) context
                                  .lookup(lookupStr);
                      // Object dispactherBean = context.lookup(lookupStr);

                      System.out.println("dispactherBean ="
                                  + dispactherBean.getClass().getCanonicalName());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();


          }
```

this is my ejb stateless bean and it's interface:

```
Stateless
@Remote(
{ DispactherBeanRemote.class })
@RemoteBinding(jndiBinding = "DispactherBean")
public class DispactherBean implements DispactherBeanRemote, Serializable
{
...
}




@Remote
public interface DispactherBeanRemote
{

    public MomDispatcherResponseMsgDTO dispatchMsg(MomDispatcherRequestMsgDTO momMessageRequestDTO);

}
```

thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add ejb3 jars to the project in order to parse the objects.